# Core Data: How to find empty fields using NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, ios4

I have a database which contains some string fields with only whitespace in them. This is not a valid situation in my case so I wish to find these fields and replace them with a predefined string.

Is there a way using NSPredicate to get only these objects or must I iterate all objects, trimm the target field and check if length is zero?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
NSString *regex = @"\s+";
NSPredicate *regexPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
```

Comment: Although, I eventually ended with iterating all objects for other reasons.. your answer seems to be in the right direction. I might use that in the future, thanks for helping!! (sorry I can't confirm as I didn't test that)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *whiteSpaceStr = @"    This      line  contains many   white       space!   ";

// OR you string could be only

NSString *whiteSpaceStr = @"     ";

while ([whiteSpaceStr rangeOfString:@"  "].location != NSNotFound) {
    whiteSpaceStr = [whiteSpaceStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@" "];
}
```